# Why doesn't my printed pages counter on my Excel VBA/UDF work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this following code that used to count how many printed page(s) on my worksheet as a formula:

```
Function PageCount() As String
 
    Application.Volatile
 
    PageCount = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")

 
End Function
```

but when I type the formula `PageCount()` on excel formula, it always make a `#VALUE!` return, meanwhile I expect to get an integer. What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Probable cause; `ExecuteExcel4Macro` isn't defined (The correct `reference` missing) such that it can be found and executed.

Comment: I think the ```ExecuteExcel4Macro``` is not gonna work when it mixed with a Function, it is only work with a Sub. But it is no problem anymore though, because I already found the solution

Comment: If you found a solution, then please answer your own question :-)  this provides help to others seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Here is the code that I wrote to count a printed page that work on a Function

```
Function PageCount()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim iHorPgs As Integer
    
    

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    iHorPgs = wks.HPageBreaks.Count + 1

    PageCount = iHorPgs
End Function
```

Note: This code is only for a Worksheet that only has pages which vertically, not which horizontally like on the picture.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]